# AMChart Libraries Usage

Tags: amcharts

when i use these scripts, charts will display.

```
<script src="http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but when i use these scripts, charts will not display (forget all those dots)

```
<script src=".../Thesis/ThesisWorkspace/AMCharts/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src=".../Thesis/ThesisWorkspace/AMCharts/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i don't know what's wrong with the scripts above.
also, where to put all those js properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example you show is taking the required JavaScript files directly from the amcharts servers.  For normal use you should place a copy of these on your own server and the location you use will be in reference to the folder the html is coming from.

Take the following file structure as an example:

```
-> webroot
| -> includes
| | -> amcharts
| | | -> amchart.js
| | | -> serial.js
| -> mygraphpage.html
```

If you have your files in this sort of arrangement you will need to refer to the files as...

```
<script src="includes/amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="includes/amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```